# Adding a domain name to Google App Engine doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to connect a domain name that I own to a GAE application. I've tried it several times, from several accounts and browsers without success - please help.

The last experiment was to create a fresh GAE instance with a Google Apps for Business account (all of them with Billing enabled).

After I press "Add Domain"

I see the "Choose Account" screen. But upon selecting my account (which IS a billed Google Apps account, and I also tried with several free accounts), the screen just reloads. It doesn't go any further.

Would appreciate any hints

Answer (score 0):

I always do it from Google Apps rather than from App Engine, like this:

- Log in to your Google Apps Control Panel ([admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com))
- Click "App Engine Apps" (if its not there, look under "More Controls")
- Click the "Add Services" button
- Under "Other Services", enter your App ID in the "Enter App ID" box
- Accept the agreement
- You should now be on the Settings page. From here, under "Web address", click "Add new URL", and enter the subdomain you want to access the app under, and select which domain (if you have more than one).
- Click Add
- You will need to configure the CNAME records as usual for whatever subdomain you entered

The above instructions are for the new style admin panel, but should be similar for the old style panel if you are still on that.